# how to show a variable in MESSAGE_TEXT in signal query in c++

Tags: c++, mysql

I am using Signal query to catch errors in my c++ programming:
in the program user has to enter a database name and i check the database if it does not exists I have to return proper error message:

```
std::string database_name;
std::cin<<database_name;
if(!exists(database_name)){
  query="SIGNAL SQLSTATE '42000' SET MYSQL_ERRNO='1049', MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Unknown database';";
}
```

how can I print the database_name variable after Unknown database?

Comment: If `query` is a `std::string`, you can use something like: `query="SIGNAL SQLSTATE '42000' SET MYSQL_ERRNO='1049', MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Unknown database "; query += database_name + "';";`

Comment: yes query is a string, but adding database_name after query does not work

Comment: What do you mean "does not work" ? what is the actual code you tried for that, and what is the error you get ?

Comment: Please post the actual code you are using now. In principle concatenation of 2 string using opeator+ should work. Could it be that `database_name` is empty ?

Comment: it worked Thanks.    query="SIGNAL SQLSTATE '42000' SET MYSQL_ERRNO='1049', MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Unknown database";
        query+= database_name + "';";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format the string using

```cpp
query = std::format( "... MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Unknown database {}'", database_name );
```

This will replace `{}` with the first string argument (`database_name`)

Or you could use a string stream like

```cpp
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << "... MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Unknown database '" << database_name << "'";
query = ss.str();
```

Comment: thanks! but format is for c++ 20 and the second one does not work!

Comment: it should be query="SIGNAL SQLSTATE '42000' SET MYSQL_ERRNO='1049', MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Unknown database";
        query+= database_name + "';";

Comment: `%s` is for `printf` family, use `{}` for `std::format` – see [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/z51hEEqjs)/[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format)

Comment: oh yeah thanks, i thought `std::format` would use same fmt

Comment: fixed it, realized appending doesnt work in C++ so use a string stream